# replace value in html with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I have:

```
value="my_string"
```

in my HTML

I want to change this to:

```
value="my_second_string"
```

I've tried

~[value="]*?["]~'

This is not working. Could someone please advise me

Comment: full\real code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regular expressions, `[]` creates a character class, so your original pattern will match any number `v`, `a`, `l`, `u`, `e`, `=`, or `"` characters (non-greedily) followed by a single `"` character.

You can use this pattern to match `value="my_string"`:

```
 ~value="[^"]*"~
```

This will match a literal `value="` followed by any number of characters other than `"`, followed by a single `"` character.